# Port mapping Google Cloud Compute

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform

I'm fairly new to GCP and figured that to learn I would upload a reactJS app to a VM instance that I made. I am also pretty new to node and react so this has all been one big learning experience for me.

I'm using an Apache server and while Im aware that the index file should be on the /var/www/html/ folder, is it possible to point this default location elsewhere for this website? Here is my logic:

if I can figure this out then I can set a structure such as:

```
/var/www/html/website_1/
/var/www/html/website_2/
/var/www/html/website_3/
```

etc where I can have my domains pointing to the respecting website on the server. Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can put more sites on the same server behind Apache, using [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) (see more [examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)).

Comment: Thank you I'm reading into this now. Very helpful looks like what I need!